# How can I run steam through a proxy?

Tags: steam, pc

I am trying to run Steam on 8 laptops for a fate at my school, however I am having issues because of the proxy in place at my school.

I know that offline mode can be used but I need online so that I can download the games as well as play multiplayer.

The WiFi is `detnsw` and the proxy server is `proxy.det.nsw.edu.au`

---

Some answers to comments:

The proxy is a re-route proxy, re-routed by the central proxy server in Sydney. They block sites that have things like games when logging in as a student but administrators & teachers have mostly unrestricted access (including all the steam servers).

Comment: If you're in your school's network, the proper action is to ask the IT to help you do it, not bypass them.

Comment: I did, they don't know how to set-up the proxy for non google chrome or internet explorer programs.

Comment: proxifier has been known to let steam launch but you will likely have many issues trying to connect to game servers.

Comment: Will it atleast allow for game downloads? We can Live Without multiplayer online if we have lan.

Comment: Are you sure the network you connect to at the campus doesn't run through that proxy itself? Usually networks at universities and schools will reroute all requests to a central proxy server, for reasons like checking the website isn't illegal and simply just logging what happens.

Comment: You could just bring the laptop home and download the games and then launch in offline mode at school. If they won't let you take the laptop home, you can download the game on your own computer and then transfer the game over USB or something.

Comment: I will explain how our proxy works, is it a re-route proxy? Yes. Is there a central proxy server? Yes, it's in Sydney. How is it re-routed? By that proxy server above, they block sites that have things like games when logging in as children but administrators & teachers have mostly free access to all (including all the steam servers, I checked).

Comment: Aequitas, I know that but the problem is that we need it on 8 laptops... If i'm lucky once it might not happen again!

Comment: then just transfer the game to all 8 laptops, also you can use @username so that the person will get a notification and can respond

Comment: if admins and teachers have access to steam servers than can you not ask them to log in for the fate?

Comment: You could try using Proxifier and set it to forward all traffic through your proxy. The most important thing is not having the credentials, but ensuring that the proxy type allows. Since Steam doesn't allow for proxy configuration straight up, you can use an external program to route all its traffic through the proxy.

Answer (score 1):

If your teachers have steam access, and this is something your school is allowing, why not just have the teacher log into the machines?

Alternately, you should be able to contact the Sydney office and explain the situation and have them temporarily give you access to the Steam servers if it's allowed by your school. You'd probably want your principle to contact them in this case rather than calling yourself.

Also, if you can play the game over direct peer-to-peer network, you don't really need to be online. Just have the teacher download the game to one machine, then copy over the local network (this will save the school some bandwidth too). Not absolutely positive, but I've never had any issues with copied games running as long as my Steam account has the game. You probably want to make sure each offline Steam copy is running a unique account though. Steam obviously would try to put in checks to prevent copies of one account playing the same game together.

Worst case scenario, you could possibly rig a cell phone as a local access point, though where I'm from it typically costs extra. You don't want to download that way, or it will cost a ton for data, but connecting to the Steam servers shouldn't be too bad.

Comment: This is not an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try seeing if there are any auto-fill proxy settings you can modify to allow you to run steam despite not being proxy compatible, also, I'm familiar with the detnsw proxy and logging in as a teacher won't do anything, it would just allow you to install without admin privileges. When opening browsers it requires you to type in you username and password (Authentication Proxy) and block certain sites if not considered appropriate (Eg, YouTube isn't accessible but Wikipedia is). (I added extra details to explain to other people).